# Getting the sum of an array with different datatypes

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Im trying to get the sum of an array containing different datatypes. The array could for example contain strings, number or arrays and my function should still be able to get the sum of the array. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to convert string values into number. I want my function to calculate the sum of the array: [2, '21', 19] and return the answer 42, but right now it converts the numbers to strings and returns '2219'.
This is what I have so far:

```
for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
if (typeof values[i] === 'string') {
      Number(values[i])
      return Number(values.reduce((i, j) => {return i + j}))
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert each element to Number instead of the final result

```js
const values = [2, '21', 19];

const sum = values.reduce((c, a) => Number(c) + Number(a));

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now, I don't know how I didn't see that

Comment: @TrailorLord no problem ! Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted for future readers

Comment: You can also use `values.reduce((c, a) => c + Number(a), 0);` to prevent repeated casting of the accumulator. This also has the benefit of working as expected when passed an array of length 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use parseInt() method.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in just "strings" and "numbers" in your list, look bellow:

```
var sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (typeof values[i] === 'string') {
    sum += Number(values[i])
  } else {
    sum += values[i]
  }
}
```