# React -- Why does this line append rather than add

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have other ways of doing the same thing .. So I am not looking for a different solution to this problem  ... I am looking for an explanation as to why if I have defined a integer, it still concatenates with `.map` as if it were a string.

I have a basic set of data retrieved from an API:

```
"data":["8","8","12","1","7","4","2"]
```

If I map it using

```
let count = response.data.metrics.data.map((item) => + parseInt(item));
```

I am having a hard time understanding why it's treating this as a string returning

```
88121743
```

When I feel like because I am parsing it as an integer it should add and come out with `42`.

Is this just an issue just using `.map`?  Can shortcut math functions be used here?

Here is my [Reproducible Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-smoke-r6orqv)

Comment: Your code gives me `[8, 8, 12, 1, 7, 4, 2]`, not a single number. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: if you actually want to sum them [Getting the sum of an array with different datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333523/getting-the-sum-of-an-array-with-different-datatypes)

Comment: @Unmitigated updated with reproducible example ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach using `Array#map` creates a new array with each element converted to a number. React renders this array as multiple text nodes, so it looks like a single string.

To sum the values, use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with `parseFloat`/`parseInt`, the `Number` function, or the unary plus operator to convert each string to a number.

```js
const visitCount = data.reduce((a,b) => a + parseFloat(b), 0);
```

Comment: Right, and like I mentioned in OP, I know about these ways of doing this ...  I don't understand why it won't work in a conventional `.map` if I have parsed it into an integer?

Comment: Ahhh  So React is outputting each instance rather than "saving it" for the next iteration?

Comment: @Zak When you give React an array to render, it renders each element as a separate node.

Comment: In any case, `map` is used to create a new array, not to get a single result from applying a specific operation to the array. It's not the correct method to use here.

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me now .. Thank you for the explanation